# return count(*) value in SQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have some code that I want to be able to run to check if a class is full before allowing a student to enroll in it.  I created the classFullCheck() function with a String currentNumberInClass, that takes the count from a sql table and compares it to class_size from another table.  I think maybe I am returning the class_id instead of the count(*) number, so this isn't working properly.  I'm also not sure where to insert the classFullCheck() function into the addClass() function to make this check work properly.

Any advice would be appreciated!

```
public static void classFullCheck() {
        try {
            String currentNumberInClass = ("SELECT class_id, COUNT(*) FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(currentNumberInClass);
            String classSize = ("SELECT class_size FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(classSize);
                if (currentNumberInClass.compareTo(classSize) >= 0){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, this class is Full!");
            }
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL) {
            SQL.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void addClass() {

        try {
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String availableClasses = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("class_name") + "\t" + rs.getString("description");
                System.out.println(availableClasses);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter Class ID from Classes Listed Above to Join: ");
            selectedClass = sc.nextLine();
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String innerJoin = (userEnterIdAsName + " has been added to " + rs.getString("class_name") + " " + rs.getString("class_id"));
                System.out.println(innerJoin);
                String student_x_classJoin = "INSERT INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id, student_name, class_id, class_name)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(student_x_classJoin);
                    pStmt.setString(1, user_entered_student_id);
                    pStmt.setString(2, userEnterIdAsName);
                    pStmt.setString(3, rs.getString("class_id"));
                    pStmt.setString(4, rs.getString("class_name"));
                    pStmt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Would you like to enroll " + userEnterIdAsName + " into another class? (Y/N)");
                    String addAdditionalClass = sc.nextLine();
                    if (addAdditionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                        addClass();
                    } else if (addAdditionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL) {
            System.out.println("Wait, This Student is already enrolled in this class!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In classFullCheck, you are comparing two strings. You need to fetch the values from the resultset to do a comparison of the numbers rather than the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need do two Query in classFullCheck()
you can do this by one this query:

```
"SELECT claclass, class_size, (SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class WHERE class_id = c.class_id ) as current_student_count
FROM ClassSelector.classes c WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass
```

you have place in class when current_student_count < class_size. 
But better solution is print list classes with count of student where class_size > current_student_count to do choice one.

Answer (score 0):

So in java jdbc you retrieve the returned result from the sql in the following way.

```
public boolean isClassFull(int classId) {
    // Sql to get count
    String classCountSql = "SELECT Count(*) as classCount FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class WHERE class_id = ?;";
    // Sql to get max count for a class
    String classSizeSql = "SELECT class_size as classSize FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = ?;";
    int classCount = 0;
    int classSize = 0;
    try(Connection connection = databaseConnection.getConnection()) {
        try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(classCountSql)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, classId);

            try(ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if(resultSet.next()){
                    classCount = resultSet.getInt("classCount");
                }
            }

        }
    try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(classSizeSql)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, classId);

            try(ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if(resultSet.next()){
                    classCount = resultSet.getInt("classSize");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return classCount >= classSize;
}
```